# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting cannot be found after upgrading to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, dll, performance-testing, visual-studio-2017, load-testing

Having recently updated from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017, I ran into a referencing issue where performance testing namespaces and dll references seem to have disappeared.

I finally figured out what had caused it, but figured a few people may run into this, so I will also be including the solution.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this you have to first load up visual studio installer (It's installed alongside Visual Studio 2017) and click on modify.

Then click on Individual components and select the items shown in this image:
Microsoft test manager
testing tools core features
Web performance and load testing tools

[image]

Make sure you restart VS 2017 after installing these, I had to do a clean and rebuild as well.

Comment: That worked for me when using VS 2017 v 15.5.6, thanks!